# Is HTMLMediaElement.muted = true portable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video, standards

I tried to mute an audio, only to find out `setAttribute` doesn't work at all under `Firefox 80.0.1` and `Chrome 85.0.4183.102`. As far as I know, that's the *standard* way of setting a boolean attribute.

```
video.setAttribute("muted", "muted");
```

Surprisingly, `video.muted = true` works. I'm not sure if it's even portable, since it's not using a standard function `SetAttribute`, and the value is [not the canonical copy of `muted`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes).

Comment: `.setAttribute()` sets it on the DOM node, not necessarily the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `muted` attribute maps to the [`.defaultMuted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/defaultMuted) IDL, not directly to the `.muted` property.

The `.muted` property is first set to this `.defaulMuted` value, but afterwards changing the `.defaultMuted` value won't change the `.muted` value.

This means that at parsing, the attribute will set the initial value of `.muted`, but then, changing the attribute won't.

```js
const vid = document.getElementById("vid");
console.log( "defaultMuted:", vid.defaultMuted ); // true (because it has the attribute)
vid.removeAttribute( "muted" ); // set defaultMuted to false
console.log("### removed Attribute");
console.log( "has attribute:", vid.getAttribute( "muted" ) !== null );
console.log( "defaultMuted:", vid.defaultMuted ); // false (no attribute anymore)
console.log( "muted:", vid.muted ); // true (still muted anyway)
vid.defaultMuted = true; // set back the attribute through IDL
console.log("### set defaultMuted to true");
console.log( "has attribute:", vid.getAttribute( "muted" ) !== null ); // "" (which is a truthy value for booleans, would have been `null` if unset)
```

```html
<video controls id="vid" muted></video>
```

The correct way to mute/unmute an HTMLMediaElement dynamically is indeed through its `.muted` property, but this won't set any attribute on the element.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. I understand `defaultMuted` reflects `muted` [as per the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-media-defaultmuted). But, how does it connect to `removeAttribute` setting `defaultMuted` not `muted`?

Comment: Your comment is hard to understand too ;P If you really understand that `.defaultMuted` property reflects the `muted` attribute, you certainly do understand that removing that boolean attribute will set `.defaultMuted` to `false`. I mean, that's what "reflects" means here.

Comment: What I meant was setting either of them shall work, right?

Comment: For what purpose? Neither will change the `.muted` property after initial parsing.

Comment: To me, `defaultMuted` looks like a proxy, and `muted` is the real one. `reflects` is the one way releationship, right? Why can't we set `muted` directly?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but doesn't this statement `While the muted IDL attribute is set to true, the media element must be muted.` from [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-media-muted) mean we can do it by `setAttribute`?

Comment: DOM attributes may only be picked up by embeds on initialization time (before any JS has run).

Comment: Thanks. So, it's useless to set `DOM` attributes after initialization. I didn't know that.

Comment: @MartingZeitler, please refrain saying non-sense, many attributes can be set through their IDL, at any time. b1sub, no, the IDL attribute is the `.muted` property, so when this `.muted` property is set to true, the media must be muted. No "reflects" is not a one way relationship, at setting it will set the attribute, at getting it will return the attribute. And no it is not useless setting attributes after initialization, only a few rare cases like this one has confusing relations. Setting the attribute clearly changes the `defaultMuted` here.